# How efficient is an integer factorizing algorithm with time complexity O(2^(n/2))?

Tags: algorithm, prime-factoring

How efficient is an integer factorizing algorithm for an n-bit number with time complexity `O(2^(n/2))` compared to other factorizing algorithms?

Comment: That is the complexity of the generic trial division up to the square root, and is quite poor compared to modern factoring algorithms. Reading the Wikipedia article on factoring algorithms, or any decent textbook on public key cryptography, would explain all this and more.

Comment: do you mean O(n^(1/2)) ?

Comment: no you can calculate all factors in O(n^(1/2)) just loop i from 1 to n^(1/2) if n%i ==0 then the factors are i and n/i

Comment: @marvel308 For factoring algorithms, complexity is usually expressed in terms of the number of bits of the number to be factored rather than in terms of the number itself. An n-bit number will be of size up to 2^n, and the square root of 2^n is 2^(n/2).

Comment: OK the question was unclear on this part, whether it is a n bit number or an number n

Answer (score 1):

Yes, trivial algorithm with checking all divisor from interval `[1..sqrt(X)]` has same complexity `O(2^(n/2))`.

[Pollard's rho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm) algorithm has complexity `O(2^(n/4))`. This one is old algorithm, easy implemented and good for not very long integer.

But modern number theory has more efficient algorithms, for example [General number field sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve) or [Pollard-Strassen Algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185524/pollard-strassen-algorithm).

You can read more about known popular factorization algorithm at [wiki list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization)

Comment: I thought that Pollard's rho was `O(2^(n/4))` rather than `O(2^(n/3))` and that furthermore this was a) conjectured rather than rigorously proved and b) an expected run-time of a probabilistic algorithm rather than the worse-case analysis of a deterministic algorithm, so in some sense this complexity isn't directly comparable to the complexity of trial division. Of course in practice it is much, much better than trial division.

Comment: I fixed the typo then, +1 on an informative answer.